# presenting a view controller using custom transition delegate getting a black screen after completion animation

Tags: ios, swift, custom-transition

My goal here is animate a second View controller view from the top of the First view with Transperent background.

I am trying to present a Second View Controller from First View Controller.

Created a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning sub class and code implemented is

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
    let finalFrameForVC = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    //        toViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(finalFrameForVC, 0, bounds.size.height)
    toViewController.view.frame = finalFrameForVC.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -bounds.size.height)
    containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, animations: {
        toViewController.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        toViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    })
}
```

conform the First View Controller to UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and implemented the below

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?{
    flipPresentAnimationController.originFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
    return flipPresentAnimationController
}
```

In the button action of the First View Controller Implemented the Presentation logic

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)

completion: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Every thing works fine but after completion of the animation I am getting the Black screen instead of the Transparent.

Note: I have a button actions in the Second View Controller, if I delete the line
   transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
 in Custom class black screen is not getting but Button actions are not calling.

Comment: because of the dangling `completion: nil)` at the end, your code doesn't even build

Comment: What, if anything, do you see in the View Debugger?  Anything of interest when you slow down animations in the sim?

Comment: try `fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0`

Comment: I found issue need to change presentaton style to overFullScreen from Default. Thanks for your reply